# Prove the sample variance is an unbiased estimator

Tags: statistics, parameter-estimation

I'm trying to prove that the sample variance is an unbiased estimator.

I know that I need to find the expected value of the sample variance estimator $$\sum_i\frac{(M_i - \bar{M})^2}{n-1}$$ but I get stuck finding the expected value of the $M_i\bar{M}$ term. Any clues?

I would also like to calculate the variance of the sample variance. In short I would like to calculate $\mathrm{Var}(M_i - \bar{M})^2$ but again that term rears its ugly head.

Comment: Assuming the $M_i$ are iid, *hint*: let $\mu = E(M_1)$. Write $\sum (M_i - \bar M)^2 = \sum (M_i - \mu)^2 - n(\bar M - \mu)^2$ by throwing $\pm \mu$ into the difference and expanding.

Comment: See the first part of my answer here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/72975/variance-of-sample-variance/73080#73080

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1701626/321264

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mean of $ \sum (X_i - \bar{X})^2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1701626/mean-of-sum-x-i-barx2)

Answer (score 2):

The only full and complete proof I could find on the internet can be found under http://economictheoryblog.wordpress.com/2012/06/28/latexlatexs2/

As goes over 70 (!) steps and shows every little formula manipulations I prefer rather not to post it here.