# Proving that Sample Variance is an unbiased estimator of Population Variance

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, variance

Using the basic definition of Sample Variance

$$\ S^{2} = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n (X_i- \bar{X})^2} {n-1} $$
I obtained expectation of $S^2$ as $ \frac{n \sigma^2}{n-1} $

How do I remove the constant factor? I saw similar questions to this on the forum but the answers listed in those are simply too complicated and use an entirely different approach than directly calculating expectation of the expression for sample mean

Edit: Steps involved in derivation

$$ E(S^2)= E \left(\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n (X_i- \bar{X})^2}{n-1} \right) \\= \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n E(X_i- \bar{X})^2}{n-1}\\=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n E(X_i^2)-2E(X_i)\bar{X}+(E(\bar{X}))^2}{n-1} \\=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n \sigma^2} {n-1}\\=\frac{n\sigma^2}{n-1}
 $$

Comment: You might ike to show us your working so that we can find your mistake

Comment: You seem to be treating $\bar{X}$ as a nonrandom element when it is random.  In your steps, we should have
$$E(X_i - \bar{X})^2 = E(X_i^2) - 2E(X_i\bar{X}) + E(\bar{X}^2)$$

Comment: can we treat $X_i$ and $\bar{X}$ as independent?

Comment: Remember that $\bar{X} = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n X_k,$ which, in particular, includes $X_i$ in the sum, so no, they aren't independent.

Comment: Duplicate of [Mean of $ \sum (X_i - \bar{X})^2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1701626/mean-of-sum-x-i-barx2).

Comment: This question was posted last September and that one a few mins back , so that's the duplicate if at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem with any "simple" evaluation of the expectation of the sample variance is that the $X_i$ and the $\bar{X}$ aren't independent.  To fix this problem, we can note the following:
$$X_i - \bar{X} = X_i - \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n X_k = \frac{n-1}{n}\left(X_i - \frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{k=1\\k\neq i}^nX_k\right) := \frac{n-1}{n}(X_i - Y_i)$$
where now $X_i - Y_i$ is the difference of two independent random variables with $E(X_i) = E(Y_i)$ and $\text{var}(Y_i) = \frac{\sigma^2}{n-1}$

Then we can show directly that
$$E(S^2) = \frac{n-1}{n}E(X_1-Y_1)^2 = \frac{n-1}{n}\text{var}(X_1-Y_1) = \frac{n-1}{n}\left(\sigma^2 + \frac{\sigma^2}{n-1}\right) = \sigma^2$$