# Let $X_1, \ldots , X_n$ be independent random variables having a common density with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$.

Tags: statistics

Let $X_1, \ldots , X_n$ be independent random variables having a common density with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$. The sample variance is defined as the random variance of the sample:

$$S^2=\frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^{n}(X_i-\bar{X})^2$$

where $\bar{X}=\frac1n\sum^n_{j=1}X_j$. Calculate $E[S^2]$.

**Attempt**

Is $X_i-\bar{X}=(X_i-\mu)-(\bar{X}-\mu)$? Assuming it is, then

$$\frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^{n}(X_i-\bar{X})=\frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^{n}(X_i-\mu)-n(\bar{X}-\mu)$$

Now,

$$E\left[\frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^{n}(X_i-\bar{X})\right]=E\left[ \frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^{n}(X_i-\mu)-n(\bar{X}-\mu) \right]$$

Comment: I think you're missing a power of 2 in your formula for $S^2$

Comment: $S^2_n$ is known to be an unbiased estimator of $\sigma^2$ under the assumptions of your problem.

Comment: @MatthewPilling In other words? I wrote the problem as is...

Comment: It follows from the definition of $\bar X$ that $\sum (X_i-\bar X)$ is just $0$. The sample variance is generally defined in terms of $(X_i-\bar X )^2$ rather than $X_i-\bar X$. Also, you can factor $\frac 1 {n-1}$ from the expectation, since it's a constant.

Comment: @OliverDiaz Can you explain?

Comment: @Acccumulation What you are telling me is that $E(X_i-\mu)=Var(X_i)=\sigma^2$?

Comment: $$\begin{align}
\sum^n_{j=1}(X_j-\bar{X})^2&=\sum^n_{j=1}X^2_j-n(\bar{X})^2=(1-\tfrac1n)\sum^n_{j=1}X^2_j-\frac2n\sum_{1\leq i<j\leq n}X_iX_j
\end{align}$$
Taking expectations yields
$$
E[S^2_n]=E[X^2_1]-\frac2{n(n-1)}\binom{n}{2}\mu^2=E[X^2_1]-\mu^2=\sigma^2$$

Comment: [Mean of $ \sum (X_i - \bar{X})^2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1701626/mean-of-sum-x-i-barx2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the definition of variance:

$$
\begin{align}
E\left(X^{2}\right)&=\sigma^{2}+\mu^{2}\\
E\left(\bar{X}^{2}\right)&=\frac{\sigma^{2}}{n}+\mu^{2}
\end{align}
$$

Then substitute these into the equation:

$$
\begin{align}
E\left(S^{2}\right)&=E\left[\frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^{n}{\left(X_{i}-\bar{X}\right)^{2}}\right]\\
\\
&= \frac{1}{n-1}E\left[\sum_{i=1}^{n}{X_{i}^{2}-n\bar{X}^{2}}\right]\\
\\
&=\frac{1}{n-1}\left[\sum_{i=1}^{n}{E\left(X_{i}^{2}\right)}-nE\left(\bar{X}^{2}\right)\right]\\
\\
&=\sigma^{2}
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{align}
\sum^n_{j=1}(X_j-\bar{X})^2&=\sum^n_{j=1}X^2_j-n(\bar{X})^2=(1-\tfrac1n)\sum^n_{j=1}X^2_j-\frac2n\sum_{1\leq i<j\leq n}X_iX_j
\end{align}$$
Taking expectations yields
$$
E[S^2_n]=E[X^2_1]-\frac2{n(n-1)}\binom{n}{2}\mu^2=E[X^2_1]-\mu^2=\sigma^2$$