# If $S'^2 = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n (Y_i - \bar{Y})^2}{n}$ and $S^2 = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n (Y_i - \bar{Y})^2}{n-1}$, find $V(S'^2)$.

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-theory, probability-distributions

If $S'^2 = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n (Y_i - \bar{Y})^2}{n}$ and $S^2 = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n (Y_i - \bar{Y})^2}{n-1}$

then $S'^2$ is a biased estimator of $σ^2$, but $S^2$ is an unbiased estimator of the same parameter. If we sample from a normal population, find $V(S'^2)$.

I already found $E(S^2) = \sigma^2$
My approach is to first find $V(S^2) = E(S^4) - [E(S^2)]^2$.
Finally, find $V(S'^2) = V(\frac{n-1}{n}S^2)$...
However, I am stuck for finding $E(S^4)$ Could someone help with this?

Comment: Similar question: [Variance of sample variance?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/72975/variance-of-sample-variance).

Comment: I just looked at it as the post use the chi squared approach which I am not so comfortable with...do you know how to solve the way I post above by finding $E(S^4)$?

Comment: The chi-squared approach only works under the assumption of normality. Have you seen this [answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/72975/variance-of-sample-variance/73080#73080)? Also, this might be of use: [Sample Variance Distribution](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SampleVarianceDistribution.html).

Comment: My question states we sample from a normal population...also i also looked at this answer but the answer seems wrong to me but the chi-squared approach gives me the right answer as I just wondering is there other ways to find the same answer such as finding $E(S^4)$?

Comment: I think that in [Sample Variance Distribution](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SampleVarianceDistribution.html) $\operatorname ES^4$ is calculated (see equation (7), for example). They just use weird notation for the expected value.

Comment: The answer I am expecting is $V(S^2) = \frac{2\sigma^4}{(n-1)}$...it does not seem like it though?

Comment: Under the assumption of normality, the fourth central moment is equal to $3\sigma^4$. Pay attention to what is calculated: $V(S^2)$ or $V(S'^2)$.

Comment: where does you see $3\sigma^4$?

Comment: There is an example under the graph: "For a normal distribution, $\mu_2=\sigma^2$ and $\mu_4=3\sigma^4$, so..."

Comment: just saw it...first how do they calculate $\mu_4$ and second where is $\frac{1}{n-1}$?

Comment: @V.C.: Do you have a follow up on my question or let me know if they are not clear?

Comment: It is a known fact that the fourth central moment of the normal distribution is equal to $3\sigma^4$, where $\sigma^2$ is the variance of the normal distribution. It is not that easy to calculate. I suggest you begin [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#Moments) if you want to know how to prove that.

Comment: OK Then where's 1/(n-1) since $V(S) = 2\sigma^4/(n-1)$?

Comment: I'm affraid I don't follow. Please, make your question more precise.

Comment: since you said $E(S^4) = 3\sigma^4$, $[E(S^2)]^2 = \sigma^4$. Then $V(S^2) = 2\sigma^4$ But $V(S^2)$ should be $2\sigma^4/(n-1)$...why is the 1/(n-1) missing?

Comment: Where did I say that?..

Comment: $\mu_4=3σ^4$...unless $\mu_4$ not equal to $E(S^4)$

Comment: $\mu_4\ne\operatorname E S^4$.

Comment: how to convert $\mu_4$ to $E(S^4)$ then?

Comment: $\operatorname ES^4$ is given by (23) in [Sample Variance Distribution](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SampleVarianceDistribution.html).

Comment: How does that relates to $2\sigma^4/(n-1)$?

Comment: too obvious? too complicated to explain?

Comment: Use the fact that $\mu_2^2=\sigma^4$, $\mu_4=3\sigma^4$ and use equation (25). You get that $\operatorname{Var}S'^2=\frac{2\sigma^4(N-1)}{N^2}$. Now $\operatorname{Var}S^2=\frac{N^2}{(N-1)^2}\operatorname{Var}S'^2=\frac{2\sigma^4}{N-1}$.