# mse of non-normal variance estimator

Tags: statistics, estimation, variance

Suppose you have a general distribution, and you have a sample of iid random variable $(X_1,X_2,...X_n)$.

We all know that the unbiased variance estimator is 
$$\hat {\sigma^2} = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n (X_i - \hat \mu)^2}{n-1} $$
Where $\hat \mu = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n X_i}{n}$

But how to calculate the variance of $\hat {\sigma^2}$?

Thank you so much!

Comment: Maybe [this Q&A](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2476527/variance-of-sample-variance) will help.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the chisquare distribution for that. $$(n-1)S^2/\sigma^2\sim\chi^2(n-1)$$

Comment: But this is only valid for the normal distribution random variable, I think the general distribution random variable is much more complicated