# Why the variance estimator can be used with X and Centered X indistinctly.

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, variance, estimation

My motivation for this question is the following question posted here: [Variance of Sample Variance](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2476527/variance-of-sample-variance?noredirect=1&lq=1)

I understood the computations and the math operations, but I'm trying to understand why, assuming that $Z_i = X_i -\mu$
$$S^2_n = \dfrac{n\sum_{i=1}^{n} X_i^2 - (\sum_{i=1}^{n} X_i)^2}{n(n-1)} = \dfrac{n\sum_{i=1}^{n} Z_i^2 - (\sum_{i=1}^{n} Z_i)^2}{n(n-1)}$$

Comment: What happens if you substitute, expand and tidy up?