# Is the variance of variance larger than the variance itself?

Tags: statistics

After performing a simulation I'm trying to analyse my results. Due to a limited number of measurements, my results are quite noisy. I notice that in calculating a mean value I have gotten somewhat good results, however, when calculating the variance the results seem to be more "all over the place".

Is this natural considering the nature of the variance, or should i investigate further, in order to find out if there is something wrong with my results. If it helps, these are measurements related to physics, and I'm considering the energy and the heat capacity.

I hope I'm not to vague, and would appreciate any answer!

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/73080/429987

Comment: Suggestion: Take a look at a histogram of your results.  There might be a reason why your results are "all over the place"--bimodality, or something like that.