# Can the variance of the sample variance be negative?

Tags: probability, variance, standard-deviation, sampling, standard-error

In this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/73080/464587) is shown that the variance of the sample variance is

$$
\text{Var}(S^2) = \frac{1}{n} \left(\mu_4 - \frac{n-3}{n-1}\sigma^4\right)
$$

where $\mu_4$ is the fourth central moment, ie $E[(X-\mu)^4]$.

My question is, what prevents the variance from being negative? As far as I know, it can happen that $\mu_4 < \frac{n-3}{n-1}\sigma^4$, and then the variance would be negative, which doesn't make sense.

Am I missing something?

Comment: I think if you work out $\mu_4$ you can bound the integral and see that this can't happen.

Comment: @Randall But this is a general formula, regardless of the underlying distribution. Do you mean that $\mu_4 > \frac{n-3}{n-1}\sigma^4$ for any $n$ and any distribution function?

Comment: The answer posted below is the type of thing I was getting at.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By [Cauchy-Schwarz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality),

$$\frac{n-3}{n-1}\sigma^4\leq \sigma^4=(E[(X-\mu)^2])^2\leq E[(X-\mu)^4]=\mu_4. $$

Comment: Or you can also see that $0\leq \text{Var}((X-\mu)^2)=E[(X-\mu)^4]-(E[(X-\mu)^2])^2=\mu_4-\sigma^2.$